# Knockoutjs keyup binding in the right context

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

My view model has array of stops. Each stop has array of pickups. I woluld like to add keyboard shortcut to addPickup. My question is how to trigger it in the context of stop - pressing ctrl-a wont add pickup to first stop, or the last one, but to one with "focus". Number of stops is dymamic. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This "works" with the event keypress binding

```
<div data-bind="event: {  keypress: keypress }">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w5URD/

Problem is that you have to focus any input or button inside the div to make it triggerable, you probably have to fix this with a custom binding